# Given that $a,b,c>0$ and $abc=1$, prove that $a+b+c+\frac{3}{ab+bc+ca} \geq 4$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, uvw

I was given some exercises from Math olympiads, and I am stuck with the one below, which seems soluble, yet I can't come up with something that works.

> Given that $a,b,c>0$ and $abc=1$, prove that $a+b+c+\frac{3}{ab+bc+ca} \geq 4$.

I tried AM-GM-HM, forming squares, but nothing appears to work.

If you have any idea on the source of this problem, that would be also welcomed.

First i tried using AM-GM for a+b+c, and then tried to prove that the remaining is >= 1. After trying, I just tested it using a=1, b=2, c=1/2, and realized that this is not true in general.

Next I tried dividing with abc, did some calculations and ended up with $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a−1)(b+c)^2\geq0$
, which also is not true. Similarly, I got $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}2\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)$
, which also is not true. Next I found an intermediate result in the web, and I was left with proving AM*HM > 1, which also is not true in this case, apparently.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): **One question per post**. Limit yourself to one question per post. Maybe (but this should be an exception rather than a rule) two closely related questions with the second question a variation of the first one.

Comment: HInt for 2: Show that for positive reals,  $ \sqrt{ ab+ac} + \sqrt{ bc+ba} + \sqrt {ca+cb} \geq \sqrt{2} (a+b+c)$.  Hence, conclude that $ 2^x = 4^y = 8^z$.

Comment: @CalvinLin thanks a lot for the hint, it definitely solves the task (assuming it is true, since I haven't proved it yet). Unfortunately, I had to delete one of the tasks: apparently is against the guidelines...

Comment: @Limsup Show me, how exactly you tried AM-GM-HM and I'll show you my solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg First i tried using AM-GM for a+b+c, and then tried to prove that the remaining is >= 1. After trying, I just tested it using a=1, b=2, c=1/2, and realized that this is not true in general.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Next I tried dividing with abc, did some calculations and ended up with $\sum_{cyc}(a-1)(b+c)^2 \geq 0$, which also is not true. Similarly, I got $\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab} \geq \sum_{cyc}2(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b})$, which also is not true. Next I found an intermediate result in the web, and I was left with proving AM*HM > 1, which also is not true in this case, apparently. I hope I have tried enough to be worthy of your mighty solution, dear Michael.

Comment: @Limsup You can post it as a separate question. Do remember to show your work through.  $\quad$ Hint for 1: All that you need is $ (a+b+c) ^2 \geq 3(ab+bc+ca)$ and $a+b+c  \geq 3$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Good point, I managed to solve it. Thanks a lot for the hint, and especially for being nice in this toxic community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$3u+\frac{w^3}{v^2}\geq 4w,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$3u+\frac{w^3}{v^2}\geq4\sqrt[4]{\frac{u^3w^3}{v^2}}\geq4\sqrt[4]{\frac{wv^2w^3}{v^2}}=4w.$$
The following inequality is also true.

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers such that $abc=1.$ Prove that:
> $$a+b+c+\frac{8}{ab+ac+bc}\geq\frac{17}{3}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on my hint, show that

1. $(a+b+c)^2 \geq 3(ab+bc+ca)$
2. $a+b+c \geq 3$
3. let $ t = a+b+c$, then $LHS \geq t + \frac{ 9}{t^2}$.
4. Finally, show that for $ t \geq 3$, $ t + \frac{9}{t^2 } \geq 4$.

   - Lots of ways to do this.

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing. In the end I studied the sign of $t^3-4t^2+9$ by expressing it as (t-3)(the rest), and for $t\geq 3$ we get exactly what we want. The first two inequalities are elementary (the first one: it follows from $a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq ab+bc+ca$, and the second one is AM-GM.

Comment: @Limsup Try Michael's followup inequality. Unfortunately this approach doesn't work, even if we set $ T = ab+bc+ca$.